# Can you apply one user settings to another user in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Is it possible to move one users settings to another user account on the same machine?

I have one user called PC and want to move all of the settings that user had to the new user on this machine.

The settings I want to move is everything from the desktop folders, taskbar, through to SQL Server and Visual Studio settings, and drop box etc.

The reason for the username change is to move from PC to my name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the [windows migration tool, "Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/transfer-files-settings-from-another-computer#1TC=windows-7)". Originally its intent is to be used to help during the migration to an new system from one pc to another, but if you use the custom options, you first migrate one user's settings (your current "PC") to a temporary directory, and then run it again, migrating those saved settings to the new user ("your name").

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am currently in the customize location for the user and see there is an advanced option. How much should I select to copy across? There is options for literally every single folder in the machine. Should I select that?

Comment: Just choose your username and nothing else. Only if it's the same pc

Comment: @CanadianLuke has the right idea. Just to minimize everything. But you'll do want the user settings that pick up your browser(s) favorites and any app settings picked up from the registry. Otherwise, the tool will offer to copy even the directories on the external drive used as the copy destination.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third party tool I find works really well called the User Profile Wizard from www.forensit.com.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks BlueBerry - vignesh4303 - perhaps you could be a little more constructive and suggest what I could have done?  You might also acknowledge that this was NOT a link only answer - the LINK is to the company that provides the software.